# JOOQ : trunc is adding `DD` to the query - which is causing query to fail

Tags: jooq

Doing some operation on a Date Field

```
Field field = (DSL.month(dateField).add(12 - startMonthOfYear).div(3));
```

Then truncating the field to get the integer value

```
Field quarterField = DSL.trunc(field2);
```

The query it generates is like

```
select trunc(((extract(month from my_date_field) + ?) / ?), 'DD') "date" from my_table
```

*trunc seems to add this 'DD'*

Now this **'DD'** is causing problem while running the query
'**ORA-01722: invalid number**'
, if I remove the **'DD'** .. the query runs completely fine.

How do I remove this **'DD'**?

**Oracle 12c is the SQL dialect**

Answer (score 0):

In jOOQ 3.16, there's currently no `TRUNC(numeric)` function support in jOOQ, only `TRUNC(date)` as you can see in the [`DSL.trunc(Field<T>)`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/impl/DSL.html#trunc(org.jooq.Field)) Javadoc:

> Truncate a date or a timestamp to the beginning of the day.

That's certainly an API design mistake, which should be fixed: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/12865

In the meantime, use [`DSL.trunc(Field<T>, int)`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/impl/DSL.html#trunc(org.jooq.Field,int)) instead.

```java
Field<?> quarterField = DSL.trunc(field, 0);
```

#### Rawtypes

A side note on your rawtype usage. It's highly recommended to avoid doing that to avoid edge cases of compilation errors or wrong overload resolution: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/11879